# The difference between this and super keywords in java (More advanced information)

Tags: java, keyword

I understand that this keyword is for calling a current constructor in the specific class. But I had another situation that I need to understand it more. The next code shows the use of this and super keywords:

```
public class Stack {
    public void push()
    {
       /* do something */
    }

    public boolean full()
    {
       /* do something */
    }
}
```

and the other class is:

```
public class ProtectedStack extends Stack {

    public void push()
    {
        if (this.full()){----}
        else
        {
            super.push();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know what will happen in this case.

Comment: `super.someMethod()` calls the method `someMethod()` in the class you extend

Comment: I am talking about this key word it has different situation in this example and that what I need to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty much explicit `this` calls the method of on the current object and `super` calls the method on the current object's parent (*Note during the call the method is searched in recursive fashion till it is found.*).

---

*from the comments*, in your case as you did not implement `full()` method on the subclass `this.full()` and `full()` and `super.full()` are identical.

Also as `this.full()` and `full()` are always same dont use `this.full()`  pattern to minimize the confusion.

Comment: might be worth mentioning that the keyword `this` is unnecessary in this context

Comment: Yes, I know that but in this case the this.full() it try to calls the full method in the parent class because there is no implementation for it in the current class. I gust see here that this keyword works as super keyword in this case.

Comment: This is a recursive process: If the `Parent` of the current class does not have the method in question, the compiler will look in the `Parent`'s `Parent` and so on. If there is no more `Parent` (i.e. if `Object` is reached) and the method is not found, you will get a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

`this.full()` is exactly the same as `full()`. It calls the method `full()` on a `ProtectedStack` instance. This method **might** be declared directly in the `ProtectedStack` class or it might be inherited. In your code, it looks like the method `full()` is inherited from the parent class `Stack`, because `ProtectedStack` does not override it.

Concerning `super.push()`, this will **always** call the method `push()` implemented in the nearest parent class. Even if this method is overriden in `ProtectedStack`, the parent method will be called.

Basically:

- `this.method()`: the method `method()` is called on this object, so the method is searched in this class, then on the parent class, etc. If this class overrides it, then this one will be called. If not, the one from the parent will be called, etc.
- `super.method()`: the method `method()` of the parent class is always called, even if this class overrides it.

Comment: I would have mentioned that if there is an explicit call to `super(..)`, it must be first instruction of the method.

Comment: @dounyy Not in this context. `super()` must be the first instruction when calling a constructor, not a method.

Comment: My bad, sorry for the lack of precision